# Azure OpenAI not able to identify the right paragraph

Tags: azure-openai

In my `azure` `openai` `playground`, I am using `text-davinci-003` model. I have created a `prompt` consisting of four paragraphs, each paragraph is summary of `jungle book story`. I then ask the questions - `Which paragraph is best to understand how old Mowgli is. Explain your choice. Do not make assumptions. Show the extract from summary which clearly mentions Mowgli's age.`

I get answer `The second paragraph is the best to understand how old Mowgli is, as it clearly states: "10 years pass, and Mowgli has grown into a wiry young boy, who has long since been adopted into his wolf pack, despite his differences."`

However, this phrase is in paragraph 4, not 2. Why `Azure` `openai` can't number the right paragraph?

Paragraph 4 is much bigger than paragraph 1,2 and 3.

```
Each paragraph below is a summary of a fictional story

`Abandoned after an accident,... man-village and stay there. (para 1 snippet)

Based on Rudyard Kipling's book... jungle or the man-village.(para 2 snippet)

Disney animation inspired by Rudyard Kipling's ... he tracks him down. (para 3 snippet)
  
The story of "The Jungle Book" concerns a young man-cub named Mowgli. A panther named Bagheera one day comes across an abandoned boat, in which a small baby is seen. Taking pity on the baby, Bagheera takes it to a small family of wolves, who adopt the boy. 10 years pass, and Mowgli has grown into a wiry young boy, ...... Bagheera happily explains that Mowgli is now where he belongs, and Baloo accepts this fact, before wrapping an arm around the panther, and the two of them return to the jungle. (para 4 snippet)`
```

Answer (score 0):

`OpenAI` was not able to understand what a paragraph is. I changed my prompt to first explain that paragraph starts with text `parastart-` and ends with text `paraend`. I gave examples of what is paragraph number.

```
Following are paragraphs of summary of a fiction book. A paragraph starts with text parastart- and ends with text paraend. A paragraph's number is the number at the end text parastart-. For example, parastart-1 is paragraph number 1, parastart-2 is paragraph number 2 and so on. 

parastart Abandoned after an accident,... man-village and stay there. paraend (para 1 snippet)

parastart Based on Rudyard Kipling's book... jungle or the man-village. paraend(para 2 snippet)

parastart Disney animation inspired by Rudyard Kipling's ... he tracks him down. paraend (para 3 snippet)
  
parastart The story of "The Jungle Book" concerns a young man-cub named Mowgli. A panther named Bagheera one day comes across an abandoned boat, in which a small baby is seen. Taking pity on the baby, Bagheera takes it to a small family of wolves, who adopt the boy. 10 years pass, and Mowgli has grown into a wiry young boy, ...... Bagheera happily explains that Mowgli is now where he belongs, and Baloo accepts this fact, before wrapping an arm around the panther, and the two of them return to the jungle. paraend (para 4 snippet)

How many paragraphs are there? What is Mowgli's age? In which paragraph is it mentioned? Explain your answer.
```